# SwiftUI Naming Classes with Same Name

Tags: xcode, class, struct, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to create a object in a class named ‘Circle’, however there is already a native struct which uses the same name(the shape). Is there any way I can keep the names for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but once you added your custom one you'll be needed to designate them, because by default swift resolves in-module, so all places where standard used should be needed to prepend with `SwiftUI.` prefix, like

```
Circle()                           // << local
SwiftUI.Circle().fill(Color.red)   // << standard
```